# Android NotificationCompat.Builder setsmallicon() not working

Tags: android, android-notifications, notification-icons

In Redmi Note 5 Pro, I am using remoteviews for custom notifications. While doing this, the resource which i am passing using setsmallicon() is not being taken and plain solid square is being displayed. The resource is being used if it is not a custom notification.

Can someone help me solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

From android version lollpop onwards, they have made the changes for the notifications. When you are specifing the small icon, it should be of specific size as mentioned in [this link](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_status_bar.html).

The important thing is the image should be **transparent** and contains only **white** color.

Try using single color white with transparent background png file and add your icon in **mipmap** folder and your problem solved.

Comment: Yes, I have done all of these. This issue is specific to the mentioned device and custom notification. The working is as expected if the notification is not custom.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add meta data in manifest with icon like this:

```
 <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
        android:resource="@drawable/notification_icon" />
```

and you have to use same notification_icon icon as setSmallIcon with NotificationCompat.Builder like this:

```
 NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
                .setLargeIcon(myBitmap)
                .setContentTitle(notification.getTitle())
                .setContentText(notification.getBody())
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
```